# How to make flexbox utilize empty space when using flex-direction as column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want flex container with `flex-direction` as `column`, to order items in the flexbox to take up empty spaces dynamically.

I have 2 different types elements in my array:

1. Short (height: 100px, width: 100px)
2. long  (height: 200px, width: 100px)

Container height is fixed as well to fit two short items and one long item i.e. 220px;

If I have following items in my array:

- Short, long, short, long, short, short, long

Then, I want them to render as:

- Short, Short, long, short, short, long (i.e. two shorts separated by long to come together to utilize empty space below single short item).

Is this possible with flex or what are the alternatives to achieve this king of layout for array of items?

Problem

[image: Problem]

[image: Expected]

Comment: It is possible with flex but you'd have to set the `order` yourself check this for more info [Order MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Comment: @Parco thanks, I considered ` order ` but for that I need to write programmatic logic in JavaScript to loop though items and then identify pattern and find the single Short items in array and bring them closer by adding ` order `.  Is there is any CSS solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-silence-2gl06?file=/src/styles.css) with a solution to your problem using grid.

The solution requires hard-coding at least some of the elements positions.

It involves the use of:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

And setting specific locations to certain elements in the container:

```
grid-column: 3 / 4;
```

To handle the case of 3 elements in the container, the changes required are:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
```

Into -->

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

p.s. according to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=grid), grid has a 96.22% support across all browsers.

Comment: If you could demo this it would be ideal. I do not think it is as simple as you might think.

Comment: Thanks you @Dandari , really appreciate that you prepared sandbox for solution, it looks good, however it still does not handle this case - Short, Long, Short   -> Expected it should render Short, Short, Long.   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5h5B.png   Thanks

Comment: Thanks @user3509547 for your feedback, i updated my answer to include the solution you required. Unfortunately, i wasn't able to come up with a dynamic solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Other than using wrappers for your various elements flexbox is not your best option here.

CSS-Grid can manage it BUT you would have to specific where you want each item to be.

`nth-child` can help here but briefly it would look something like this:

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.tall {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item tall">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item tall">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D but this is more static/hard-coded, can I use item:nth-child(5) dynamically ? How would I know which item in dynamic array should occupy space in nth Column which has only one item

Comment: You can still select every 5th child. This is just a demonstration.